# Standard unicode operators in purescript

Tags: purescript

Looking at this:

- https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/1929

I see there is support for unicode in purescript, e.g.

```
id :: ∀ a. a -> a
```

Is there a list of default operators somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The available "default" symbols are just those that are part of the syntax:

- `∀` (`forall`) for types
- `∷` (`::`) for type annotations
- `→` (`->`) for function types and cases
- `←` (`<-`) for `do` binds
- `⇒` (`=>`) for class constraints
- `⇐` (`<=`) for superclass implications

Some libraries and project preludes provide additional unicode operators for library code.

Comment: Thanks gb! The "default" list is what I was looking for.